# Google analytics cross domain tracking doesn't work - unable to pass cid

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

Edited original post...

I am implementing cross-domain tracking to track a single user across 2 domains. Users can start the property search on site A, then search parameters are passed to site B (where the search is executed and results displayed).

If the user doesn't perform a search on site A and clicks on the link that simply takes him to site B, the cross-domain tracking works fine and the linker is displayed in the URL.

Example:
https://Site-b.com/?_ga=2.132495758.1850407374.1621365224-281638599.1621363166

The problem is when the user performs the search and after search click search parameters are passed to the Site B side, I lose ga linker.

Example (destination url after search click on Site A (ga= is gone)):

[https://Site-B.com/search?s[locations][0][city]=Florida&s[locations][0][state]=PR](https://Site-B.com/search?s%5Blocations%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcity%5D=Florida&s%5Blocations%5D%5B0%5D%5Bstate%5D=PR)

[image]

[Here is Site A link](https://www.homehunt.com/) (site is not finished yet, to test type Florida and pick any suggested item)

Answer (score 0):

You have to click in a link from A site to B site to pass _ga parameter, it is not works with a redirect.